# What is the effect of denying Full Control?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

If I add a Deny entry on Full Control for a group, what will happen to a share's permissions? Will the group still be able to read?

Comment: I adjusted your tags to include [windows] because I'm fairly certain that only Windows has a permissions interface that includes the phrase Full Control. If my guess was wrong, you can revert the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Denying *Full Control* will deny all permissions to the user or group that you say. Deny entries take precedence over Allow entries (under normal circumstances), so even if there's an Allow entry for specific permissions, the principal will still be denied.

Note that the owner (or owners, if it's a group) of the object can always read and write the permissions, which makes it possible for it/them to remove the Deny entry. If that's a problem, set the owner of the object to Administrators.